# How to be certain that an xgboost training code creates the separetely given xgboost model in a pickle file?

Tags: python, pickle, xgboost

I was given a pickle file that has an xgboost model in it. I also have a  model training code. I need to check if that saved model was created by this training code. What should I do?

I tried to get some predictions for a test dataset from both the saved model and the model created by the training code. But the predictions are not a 100% match. Is looking at the model parameters enough? I'm a bit stuck, couldn't find a solution. Thanks in advance.